# Getting IndexError: string index out of range while fetching data from a Treeview Widget (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Good Day to everyone. I have two treeview widgets (one is in tab 1 and the other in tab 2) linked to mysql database. After the registration of the form in tab 1, I want to fetch some of the data from the treeview in the tab 1 to the treeview in the tab 2 or automatically populate treeview in tab 2 with the selected items from tab 1's treeview but i keep on getting IndexError: string index out of range particularly with the Student_ID. I don't know why it's out of reach. Please for the purpose of the question, i have removed most of the codes just to make it small so i can post it here.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import mysql.connector

root = Tk()
root.title('School Management System')
root.geometry("1400x700")

## ------------------------- TABS  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
tabcontrol = ttk.Notebook(root)
# tabcontrol.grid()
tabcontrol.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

tab1 = Frame(tabcontrol)
tabcontrol.add(tab1, text='Registration')

tab2 = Frame(tabcontrol)
tabcontrol.add(tab2, text='Class Score (30%)')

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### ------------------------------- TAB 1 (FRAMES 1) ----------------------------------------------------------------------

frame1 = Frame(tab1)
frame1.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.05, relheight=0.90, relwidth=0.45)
frame1.configure(relief=GROOVE)
frame1.configure(borderwidth="2")

text_surname = StringVar()
text_other_names = StringVar()
text_gender = StringVar()
class_ = StringVar()
text_age = StringVar()
text_student_id = StringVar()
text_full_name = StringVar()
text_date_of_vacation = StringVar()
text_position_in_class = StringVar()



label1 = Label(frame1, text="------------- REGISTRATION FORM -------------")
label1.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.15)

surname = Label(frame1, text="Surname")
surname.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.22)
txtsurname = Entry(frame1, width=20, textvariable=text_surname)
txtsurname.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.22)

othername = Label(frame1, text="Other Names")
othername.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.28)
txtothername = Entry(frame1, width=20, textvariable=text_other_names)
txtothername.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.28)


gender = Label(frame1, text="Gender")
gender.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.34)
txtgender = Combobox(frame1, textvariable=text_gender)
txtgender['values'] = ('Male', 'Female')
txtgender.place(relx=0.15,  rely=0.34)


age = Label(frame1, text="Age")
age.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.46)
txtage = Entry(frame1, width=20, textvariable=text_age)
txtage.place(relx=0.15, rely=0.46)



####----------------------------------------End--------------------------------------------------

studentid = Label(frame1, text="Student ID")
studentid.place(relx=0.56, rely=0.28)
txtstudentid = Entry(frame1, textvariable=text_student_id)
txtstudentid.place(relx=0.68, rely=0.28)

Class = Label(frame1, text="Class")
Class.place(relx=0.60, rely=0.34)
txtClass = Combobox(frame1, textvariable=class_, justify=CENTER)
txtClass.place(relx=0.68, rely=0.34, relwidth=0.20)
txtClass.config(values=("Class 1", "Class 2", "Class 3", "Class 4", "Class 5", "Class 6",
                        "JHS 1", "JHS 2", "JHS 3", "Completed", "Stopped"))


## --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


### ------------------------------- FRAMES 2 ----------------------------------------------------------------------

frame2 = Frame(tab1)
frame2.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.05, relheight=0.90, relwidth=0.50)
frame2.configure(relief=GROOVE)
frame2.configure(borderwidth="2")

frame_2 = Frame(tab1)
frame_2.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.12, relheight=0.83, relwidth=0.50)
frame_2.configure(relief=GROOVE)
frame_2.configure(borderwidth="2")


list_of_students = []

Class = Label(frame2, text="Class")
Class.place(relx=0.60, rely=0.03)
txtClass = Combobox(frame2, justify=CENTER)
txtClass.place(relx=0.66, rely=0.03, relwidth=0.20)
txtClass.config(values=("Class 1", "Class 2", "Class 3", "Class 4", "Class 5", "Class 6",
                        "JHS 1", "JHS 2", "JHS 3", "Completed", "Stopped"))


listofstudents = Label(frame2, text="List Of Students")
listofstudents.place(relx=0.20, rely=0.03)

## --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### ------------------------------- TAB 2 ---------------------------------------------------------------

frame3 = Frame(tab2)
frame3.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.02, relheight=0.20, relwidth=0.94)
frame3.configure(relief=GROOVE)
frame3.configure(borderwidth="2")


full_name = Label(frame3, text="Full Name ")
full_name.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.05)
txtfull_name = Entry(frame3, width=30, textvariable=text_full_name)
txtfull_name.place(relx=0.09, rely=0.05)

def set_label(name, index, mode):
    text_full_name.set(text_surname.get() + '  ' + text_other_names.get())


text_surname.trace('w', set_label)
text_other_names.trace('w', set_label)

text_surname.set('')
text_other_names.set('')


age = Label(frame3, text="Age")
age.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.26)
txtage = Entry(frame3, width=20, textvariable=text_age)
txtage.place(relx=0.13, rely=0.26)

Class = Label(frame3, text="Class")
Class.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.48)
txtClass = Entry(frame3, textvariable=class_, justify=CENTER)
txtClass.place(relx=0.13, rely=0.48)


dateofvacation = Label(frame3, text="Date Of Vacation")
dateofvacation.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.70)
dateofvacation = Entry(frame3, textvariable=text_date_of_vacation)
dateofvacation.place(relx=0.13, rely=0.70)

gender = Label(frame3, text="Gender")
gender.place(relx=0.28, rely=0.05)
txtgender = Entry(frame3, textvariable=text_gender)
txtgender.place(relx=0.36, rely=0.05)


studentid = Label(frame3, text="Student ID")
studentid.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.05)
txtstudentid = Entry(frame3, textvariable=text_student_id)
txtstudentid.place(relx=0.60, rely=0.05)

position = Label(frame3, text="Position In Class")
position.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.24)
position = Entry(frame3, textvariable=text_position_in_class)
position.place(relx=0.60, rely=0.24)


frame4 = Frame(tab2)
frame4.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.20, relheight=0.75, relwidth=0.94)
frame4.configure(relief=GROOVE)
frame4.configure(borderwidth="2")

text_listStd = []
list_students = Label(frame4, text="LIST OF STUDENTS")
list_students.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.05)
list_students = Entry(frame4, textvariable=text_listStd)
list_students.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.09, relwidth=0.15)


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="billstone10", db="rock")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Student_ID varchar(20),
Surname varchar(20), Other_Names varchar(20), Full_Name varchar(20), Gender varchar(10), Class varchar(10), Age varchar(10))""")
con.commit()
con.close()

def addrec():
    con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="billstone10", db="rock")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO info(Student_ID, Surname, Other_Names, Full_Name, Gender, Class, Age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, "
                "%s, %s, %s, %s)", (text_student_id.get(), text_surname.get(), text_other_names.get(),
                                    text_full_name.get(), text_gender.get(), class_.get(), text_age.get()))
    con.commit()
    fetch()
    clearData()
    con.close()

def fetch():
    con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="billstone10", db="rock")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT Student_ID, Surname, Other_Names, Gender, Class, Age FROM info")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    if len(rows) != 0:
        student_list.delete(*student_list.get_children())
        for row in rows:
            student_list.insert("", END, values=row)
        con.commit()
    con.close()

def clearData():
    txtsurname.delete(0, END)
    txtothername.delete(0, END)
    txtgender.delete(0, END)
    txtage.delete(0, END)
    txtstudentid.delete(0, END)
    txtClass.delete(0, END)

def get_cursor(ev):
    cursor_row = student_list.focus()
    content = student_list.item(cursor_row)
    row = content['values']
    text_student_id.set(row[0]),
    text_surname.set(row[1]),
    text_other_names.set(row[2]),
    text_gender.set(row[3]),
    class_.set(row[4]),
    text_age.set(row[5]),

scrollbary = Scrollbar(frame_2, orient=VERTICAL)
scrollbarx = Scrollbar(frame_2, orient=HORIZONTAL)
student_list = ttk.Treeview(frame_2, columns=("Student_ID", "Surname", "Other_Names", "Gender", "Class", "Age"),
                            selectmode="extended",
                    height=500, yscrollcommand=scrollbary.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set)
scrollbary.config(command=student_list.yview)
scrollbary.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbarx.config(command=student_list.xview)
scrollbarx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
student_list.heading('Student_ID', text="Student_ID", anchor=W)
student_list.heading('Surname', text="Surname", anchor=W)
student_list.heading('Other_Names', text="Other Names", anchor=W)
student_list.heading('Gender', text="Gender", anchor=W)
student_list.heading('Gender', text="Gender", anchor=W)
student_list.heading('Class', text="Class", anchor=W)
student_list.heading('Age', text="Age", anchor=W)
student_list.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
student_list.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=80)
student_list.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=80)
student_list.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
student_list.column('#3', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=80)
student_list.column('#4', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=150)
student_list.column('#5', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
student_list.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", get_cursor)
fetch()
student_list.place(relx=0.00, rely=0.00, relheight=0.97, relwidth=0.97)


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="billstone10", db="rock")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, Student_ID varchar(20), 
Date_of_Vacation varchar(10), Position_In varchar(10), FOREIGN KEY(Student_ID) REFERENCES info(Student_ID))""")
con.commit()
con.close()


def addrec2():
    con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="billstone10", db="rock")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO profile(Student_ID, Date_of_Vacation, Position_In) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                (text_student_id.get(), text_date_of_vacation.get(), text_position_in_class.get()))
    con.commit()
    fetch2()
    con.close()

def fetch2():
    con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="billstone10", db="rock")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT inn.Student_ID, inn.Full_Name, inn.Gender, inn.Class, inn.Age, Date_of_Vacation, Position_In "
                "FROM info AS inn, profile")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    if len(rows) != 0:
        student_list_a.delete(*student_list_a.get_children())
        for row in rows:
            student_list_a.insert("", END, values=row)
        con.commit()
    con.close()

def get_cursor_a(ev):
    cursor_row_a = student_list_a.focus()
    content_a = student_list_a.item(cursor_row_a)
    row_a = content_a['values']
    text_student_id.set(row_a[0]),
    text_full_name.set(row_a[1]),
    text_gender.set(row_a[2]),
    class_.set(row_a[3]),
    text_age.set(row_a[4]),

scrollbary = Scrollbar(frame4, orient=VERTICAL)
scrollbarx = Scrollbar(frame4, orient=HORIZONTAL)
student_list_a = ttk.Treeview(frame4, columns=("Student_ID", "Surname", "Other_Names", "Gender", "Class", "Age"),
                            selectmode="extended", height=500, yscrollcommand=scrollbary.set,
                              xscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set)
scrollbary.config(command=student_list_a.yview)
scrollbary.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbarx.config(command=student_list_a.xview)
scrollbarx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
student_list_a.heading('Student_ID', text="Student_ID", anchor=W)
student_list_a.heading('Surname', text="Surname", anchor=W)
student_list_a.heading('Other_Names', text="Other Names", anchor=W)
student_list_a.heading('Gender', text="Gender", anchor=W)
student_list_a.heading('Class', text="Class", anchor=W)
student_list_a.heading('Age', text="Age", anchor=W)
student_list_a.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
student_list_a.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=80)
student_list_a.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=80)
student_list_a.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
student_list_a.column('#3', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=80)
student_list_a.column('#4', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=150)
student_list_a.column('#5', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
student_list_a.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", get_cursor_a)
fetch()
fetch2()
student_list_a.place(relx=0.00, rely=0.00, relheight=0.97, relwidth=0.97)


#================================= Buttons ======================================================================

regbtn = Button(frame1, text='Register', command=addrec)
regbtn.place(relx=0.10, rely=0.94, relwidth=0.10)


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
regbtn = Button(frame4, text='Register', command=addrec2)
regbtn.place(relx=0.10, rely=0.94, relwidth=0.10)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why-does-my-ttk-treeview-click-handler-return-the-wrong-item-on-tree-focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023721)

Comment: @stovfl thanks for the response. I tried using the bindtags and it's working

Comment: Consider to close the question as duplicate.