# why does my function runs one click behind?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have tried to reconstruct a problem I am encountering in a project I am developing where my function seems to be running one click behind.

I have 3 spinboxes. Any given combination of the values in the first two spinboxes should determine the value of the third one, which is taken from some nested lists.

For example '0' in spinbox_1 and 'A' in spinbox_2, should set the value of spinbox_3 to '1'. and '1' and 'A' in spinboxes_2 and _3, to  '4' in spinbox_3. However, scrolling spinbox_1 up from '0' to '1' leaves spinbox_3 the same - and it is only when I click again that it changes to '4', by which time it should be changing from '4' to '7'.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()

sp1_values = [0, 1, 2]
abc_values = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

def set_default_in_sp3(args):
    selected = var1.get()
    idx = selected
    lvl = var2.get()
    if idx == 0:
        if lvl == 'A':
            var3.set(abc_values[0][0])
        if lvl == 'B':
            var3.set(abc_values[0][1])
        if lvl == 'C':
            var3.set(abc_values[0][2])
    if idx == 1:
        if lvl == 'A':
            var3.set(abc_values[1][0])
        if lvl == 'B':
            var3.set(abc_values[1][1])
        if lvl == 'C':
            var3.set(abc_values[1][2])
    if idx == 2:
        if lvl == 'A':
            var3.set(abc_values[2][0])
        if lvl == 'B':
            var3.set(abc_values[2][1])
        if lvl == 'C':
            var3.set(abc_values[2][2])

var1 = tk.IntVar()
var2 = tk.StringVar()
var3 = tk.IntVar()

spinbox_1=tk.Spinbox(textvariable=var1, values=sp1_values)
spinbox_1.pack()
spinbox_1.bind('<Button-1>', set_default_in_sp3)

spinbox_2=tk.Spinbox(values=('A', 'B', 'C'), textvariable = var2)
spinbox_2.pack()

spinbox_3=tk.Spinbox(from_=1, to=10, increment=1, textvariable = var3)
spinbox_3.pack()
spinbox_3.bind('<Button-1>', set_default_in_sp3)

root.mainloop()
```

In an answer to a similar problem also posted on SO ([Tkinter Label bound to StringVar is one click behind when updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931053/tkinter-label-bound-to-stringvar-is-one-click-behind-when-updating)), involving a listbox and a label it was suggested that "the best solution is to bind to the virtual event 'ListboxSelect', and as far as I can see there is no comparable virtual event for the spinbox widget in Tkinter.

How can I go about solving this problem?

Comment: `spinbox` has a command attribute that lets you specify a function to call after a change has been made.

Comment: This does seem to work -thanks. However, in the project I am working on, the command attribute has been assigned to another function for each of the spinboxes, is there a way of assigning multiple functions to a command attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bryan Oakley said, you can use the `command` option on the `Spinbox`es to specify a function to be called when they change. You also don't need to bind the mouse button to each one. I also noticed and removed some of the repeated code you had in the function `set_default_in_sp3`.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()

sp1_values = [0, 1, 2]
abc_values = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

def set_default_in_sp3(*args):
    idx = int(var1.get())
    lvl = var2.get()
    if lvl == 'A':
        var3.set(abc_values[idx][0])
    if lvl == 'B':
        var3.set(abc_values[idx][1])
    if lvl == 'C':
        var3.set(abc_values[idx][2])

var1 = tk.IntVar()
var2 = tk.StringVar()
var3 = tk.IntVar()

spinbox_1=tk.Spinbox(textvariable=var1, values=sp1_values, command=set_default_in_sp3)
spinbox_1.pack()

spinbox_2=tk.Spinbox(values=('A', 'B', 'C'), textvariable=var2, command=set_default_in_sp3)
spinbox_2.pack()

spinbox_3=tk.Spinbox(from_=1, to=10, increment=1, textvariable=var3,
                     command=set_default_in_sp3)
spinbox_3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can't assign multiple functions to a `command` callback, but you can write another function that calls one or more other functions and use its name in the `Spinbox` constructors.