# updating a label text by listbox binding in tkinter is one click behind

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a listbox, where an item that has been clicked on updates a label text. The problem is, that the label text shows the item i clicked on the previous click. So if I click on item 3 and then on item 2, item 3 is shown in the label.

Here's the relevant code:

```
class MainWindow(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.parent.geometry(MAIN_GEOMETRY)
        self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)

        self.standin_list = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]

        self.titles_listbox = tk.Listbox(parent, width=80)
        self.titles_listbox.grid()
        self.titles_listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.update_label)
        self.fill_listbox()
        self.selected_label = tk.Label(parent, text="nothing selected...")
        self.selected_label.grid()

    def fill_listbox(self):
        self.update_listbox(self.standin_list)

    def update_listbox(self, formatted_titles_list):
        self.titles_listbox.delete(0, END)
        for item in formatted_titles_list:
            self.titles_listbox.insert(END, item)

    def update_label(self, event):
        print(self.titles_listbox.curselection())
        self.selected_label.config(text=self.titles_listbox.get(ACTIVE))
```

when I printing

```
listbox.curselection()
```

in the bound function, the right position is reflected. Where does that "delay" of one click come from?

In an answer to a similar problem ([Tkinter Label bound to StringVar is one click behind when updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931053/tkinter-label-bound-to-stringvar-is-one-click-behind-when-updating)) binding to `<<ListboxSelect>>` solved the problem, here it still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where does that "delay" of one click come from?

The `<<ListboxSelect>>` event fires before the active element is changed. The active element and the selected element are not always going to be the same thing.

If you want the text of the selected element, use the index provided by `curselection` rather than getting the active element.

```
def update_label(self, event):
    selection = self.titles_listbox.curselection()
    if selection:
        text = self.titles_listbox.get(selection[0])
        self.selected_label.config(text=text)
```